# How to require all Controller and Action to login to guests using already a code with multiple roles' actions?

Tags: php, yii2

I have this `behaviors` in **SiteController**

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    //El administrador tiene permisos sobre las siguientes acciones
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    //Esta propiedad establece que tiene permisos
                    'allow' => true,
                    //Usuarios autenticados, el signo ? es para invitados
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    //Este método nos permite crear un filtro sobre la identidad del usuario
                    //y así establecer si tiene permisos o no
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        //Llamada al método que comprueba si es un administrador
                        return User::isUserAdmin(Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor);
                    },
                ],
                [
                   //Los usuarios simples tienen permisos sobre las siguientes acciones
                   'actions' => ['logout'],
                   //Esta propiedad establece que tiene permisos
                   'allow' => true,
                   //Usuarios autenticados, el signo ? es para invitados
                   'roles' => ['@'],
                   //Este método nos permite crear un filtro sobre la identidad del usuario
                   //y así establecer si tiene permisos o no
                   'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                      //Llamada al método que comprueba si es un usuario simple
                      return User::isUserSimple(Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor);
                  },
               ],
            ],
        ],
 //Controla el modo en que se accede a las acciones, en este ejemplo a la acción logout
 //sólo se puede acceder a través del método post
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

But I don't know how to implement that the guests must need to login to access any action, even when they enter the main page. I know I have to put `BeforeRequest` before the `rules`, but I think it will affect the actions for the multiple logged users' roles. I need help, please.

Comment: I don't know anything about yii2, but have you checked [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code i will work

```
 public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            //'only' => ['logout', 'signup','index'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup', 'login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],///guest user//
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index','test'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],///login user///
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
            // 'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```